# My EXE file is not working after conversion

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I have used a digital clock script in Python, and I tried to convert it to an .exe file/app using pyinstaller as follows:

```
pyinstaller --onedir --onefile clock1.py
```

and I also tried

```
pyinstaller --onefile clock1.py
```

and I also tried

```
pyinstaller -w --onefile clock1.py
```

Now it compiles....without any issues apparently...
But when I try to run it, nothing happens...not even an error message.

Here is the python file: (thanks to PROGRAMMED for the tutorial and code)

```
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime
from time import strftime
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


def main():
    pass

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1280x720')
root.minsize(820,200)
root.title("Digital Clock")

# SETTING BACKGROUND
img1=Image.open("g3.jpg")
img2=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img1)
Label(root, image=img2).place(x=0,y=2)

f1=Frame(root, width=820, height=200, bg="#0E1013")
#f1.place(x=0, y=0)
f1.pack(expand=True)

a=datetime.today().strftime("%A")
b=a.upper()
c=b[0:2]

def time():
    a=strftime("%H  :  %M  :  %S")
    l1.config(text=a)
    l1.after(1000, time)

l1=Label(f1, font=("Century Gothic", 60), bg="#0E1013", foreground="#D3D3D3")
l1.place(x=300, y=15)
time()

l2=Label(f1, font=("Century Gothic", 60), bg="#0E1013", foreground="#D3D3D3")
l2.config(text=c+"  |")
l2.place(x=80, y=15)

def labels():
    l3=Label(f1, font=("Century Gothic", 12), bg="#0E1013", fg="#D3D3D3", text = "DAY")
    l3.place(x=90, y=130)

    l4=Label(f1, font=("Century Gothic", 12), bg="#0E1013", fg="#D3D3D3", text = "HOURS")
    l4.place(x=320, y=130)

    l5=Label(f1, font=("Century Gothic", 12), bg="#0E1013", fg="#D3D3D3", text = "MINUTES")
    l5.place(x=510, y=130)

    l6=Label(f1, font=("Century Gothic", 12), bg="#0E1013", fg="#D3D3D3", text = "SECONDS")
    l6.place(x=705, y=130)


labels()

#root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here's the [`g3.img`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCzXN.jpg) image file used for background.

If you want to add an image to make it run, just create one and call it g3.img

The python script runs fine...just wondering why I get nothing after converting it to an EXE and trying to run it...oh and I did copy the image file to the DIST folder after I made the EXE file.

Comment: You commented-out the `root.mainloop()` call which is what makes the GUI of a tkinter app run plys your `main()` function does nothing — so your results are what would be expected (compiled or not).

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it works if you just run it without converting it to .exe file?

You should uncomment the main loop:

```
root.mainloop()
```

instead of

```
#root.mainloop()
```

because this line actually runs the GUI, other lines just define it.

Comment: such a simple error...thanks heaps...that did the trick

Comment: @metaphyzikal No problem, can you accept the answer please?